# Angular localize running on single instance

Tags: angular, localization, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-localize

I am trying to run angular localize on ssr instead of ngx-translate. For now I can do `ng serve --configuration=en-US` and application is served in language I choose. But how can I do it on single instance running that user should be able to change language. I dont care if website is reloaded I just dont want to have more instances running.